# How to determine when to accelerate and decelerate to reach a given destination?

Tags: physics, motion, kinematics

I'm creating a computer game in which there is a computer-controlled car that needs to travel along a straight line (thus making this problem effectively 1-dimensional) and reach a destination coming to a rest at 0 velocity. This car "thinks" every second and decides whether (and by how much) to accelerate or decelerate.

To summarize, I want the car to accelerate as strongly as possible and then stop as rapidly as possible.

Here are the variables that the car must respect:
- `RemainingDistance` = Our current remaining distance to the destination in meters.
- `Velocity` = Our current velocity towards the destination in meters/second.
- `MaxVelocity` = The maximum speed the car can reach.
- `Acceleration` = The change in velocity per second. The car can change its acceleration every second to any number in the range [0, Acceleration].
- `Deceleration` = The change in velocity per second. The car can change its deceleration every second to any number in the range [0, Deceleration].

So to be as clear as I can, here's the math that runs every second to update the car simulation:

`Acceleration` = some amount between [`Deceleration`, `Acceleration`] as chosen by the computer

`Velocity` = `Velocity` + `Acceleration`

`RemainingDistance` = `RemainingDistance` - `Velocity`

So my question is: Every time the car "thinks", what formula(s) should it use to determine the ideal value of `Acceleration` in order to reach its destination (with a 0 final velocity) in as little time as possible?

(In the event that the car's initial velocity is too high and it can't decelerate fast enough to achieve 0 velocity by the time it reaches its destination, then it should come to a rest as close as possible to the destination.)

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: You first have to do your math. I think necessary equations are here: https://revisionmaths.com/advanced-level-maths-revision/mechanics/acceleration

Comment: Do you understand the basic kinematic equations, such as @Melon points to? You have to understand these, or you won't be able to implement them.